# by connecting c# and mysql how to drop a db create it again and connect?

Tags: c#, mysql

after connecting to database in C#

```
string MyConString2 = "SERVER=localhost;" + "user id=mytest;" + "DATABASE=clusters;" + "PASSWORD=mypass;";
```

I have an algorithm which I need to after each run of algorithm that will fill the database, drop the database "clusters" of mysql manually and again connect to the empty database and run it again,gaining new data in tables
I want to make it automatically how can I drop or empty my database if exists in C# and then run my algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

Here is example code that works and I think this is what you are talking about, if not, feel free to correct me.

```
using (var connection = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user=root;password="))
{
    connection.Open();

    var command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "drop schema if exists clusters";
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "create schema clusters";
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prepare sql query for clearing your DB and test it in f.e. MySQL workbench. Following this, just execute it as you would execute regular query against DB in C#. One way is to clear all the tables in your database by using TRUNCATE statement and the second way is to DROP DATABASE and recreate it.

Comment: you mean I should connect to db drop the db which I am connecting? then create the db? I can't understand your mean

Comment: If you are connected to the MySQL server (and initial catalog or database is not specified in connection string) then you should be able to drop the database. I don't know if this is possible when you specify initial catalog but I guess you can do it either (however I haven't tested this option by myself)

Comment: as you see in my question for connecting you should enter your database so it is not possible